# clojure / transducers / comp -- implementation -- confused

Tags: clojure

## Goal

I'm trying to understand how transducers are *implemented*.

## Confusion

I'm looking at `comp`, implement [here](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/010864f8ed828f8d261807b7345f1a539c5b20df/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L2459-L2463).

In particular, these lines here:

```
   ([] (f (g)))
   ([x] (f (g x)))
   ([x y] (f (g x y)))
   ([x y z] (f (g x y z)))
   ([x y z & args] (f (apply g x y z args)))))
```

Now, what I don't understand -- why are there five cases? Could this not have been rewritten as:

```
(args (f (apply g args)))
```

?

Is there any particular reason why the code was written as above?

Comment: @ClojureMostly : 1) I agree, these two questions are basically the same. 2) What is standard procedure for this? Do we delete the question? Mark it as duplicate? or Something else?

Comment: deleting is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could this not have been rewritten as `(args (f (apply g args)))`?

- Yes, but this has nothing to do with transducers.
- `comp` performs functional composition, whether or not the function 
  arguments are transducers.
- Many core functions, including `comp`, specialise simple cases for speed.

The general question, as @ClojureMostly notes, is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818602/why-such-implementation-of-partial-in-clojure-core).